# tablesorter column show/hide functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am wondering whether tablesorter having column show/hide functionality like FlexiGrid does as the following image:

[image]

The users can select the columns that they want to view.

Is there a plugin for that or any workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well think of the table as an array of data. If you go over every `tr` within the `tbody`

You can select its columns by index. Its been a while since Ive done something like this but the basis is just like an array the indexing starts at 0 so you can go down the rows in an each statement. I can't think of a good example off the top of my head, but in cases where I needed to do similar, there was no way I found short of doing an each over every row for every column

col3 row1 index = 2
col3 row2 index = 5
col3 row3 index = 8

if that makes sense for ya. I wish I could offer better at the time.

if your iterate down the line and `.hide()` the ones equal to that formula you should be able to show/hide the ones according to the ticks.

Comment: Are you using `tablesorter`? I think I understand what you talking about, but it would be great if you can provide a jsFiddle. I am not sure how to apply you idea in my `tablesorter`.

Comment: Its not specific to tablesorter. Its just how tables have to be handled due to the way the DOM builds it out. I will see if I can come up with an example for ya soon enough. Been a long day.